# ways to convert values read from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net, type-conversion

Every now and then I find my ADO.NET code crashes due to values read from database were null and cannot be converted to other data types. I find it very hard to find a right way to convert these read values from database. I know these methods of making the null check, but wanted to know which one them is more efficient?

1. I often use the `isnull()` method in DB (in my case that's SQL Server)
2. I convert the read value into string using the `.ToString()` and then use the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method to check whether it is null or otherwise convert it to the desired datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be able to use these data in your application without any type conversion.

Comment: well thank you for your Answer but i am afraid that you cannot convert nullable Types to other datatypes as double,float,int etc..because at times i need to Apply some business logic to the data read and for that case the data has to be converted..

Comment: @khalidkhan: No, the data doesn't have to be converted. This is actually a scenario to use nullable types in. You might find the [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) and the [GetValueOrDefault method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check against DBNull.Value. Or when you get the value use TryParse to convert it. Then if it's null it won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use new [??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173224.aspx) operator:

```
var foo = dataset.tables[0].foo ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider writing some extension methods to take the pain out of it.

Firstly, you'd need something for the nullable types, e.g:

```
public static partial class ShortExtensionMethods
{
    public static short SafeValue(this short? self)
    {
        return self == null ? 0 : self.Value;
    }
}
```

Repeat for the other basic types.  Now, you mention in your question that you want to do some conversion...  time for another generic extension method:

```
public static partial class IConvertibleExtensionMethods
{
    public static T To<T>(this IConvertible self)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(self, typeof(T));
    }   // eo To<T>

}   // eo class IConvertibleExtensionMethods
```

Now, you can read your nullable types safely:

```
short? field;

// later

short result = field.SafeValue();
int converted = field.SafeValue().To<int>();
```